# VLC media player, conneting to IPTV

Tags: vlc

Background:

I am trying to connect to my school's IPTV system.
I can connect by using VLC player on a Windows machine.
Currently I am trying to connect to IPTV with VLC on an Ubuntu machine.
I keep getting this error.

```
Your input can't be opened:
VLC is unable to open the MRL ' http://iptv.byu.edu/player/downloadPlaylist.htm'. Check the log for details.
```

Worked just fine on the windows machine, same 'MRL'.

Any tips?  Direct me to where I can get better help?
Thanks.

Comment: What Ubuntu and VLC versions are you usng?

Comment: `Check the log for details` it says. Did you? And can you post what it says in the log file?

Comment: look out for the white space in front of your MRL... 
I am not sure how you managed to get a Whitespace in front of your MRL, since vlc trims whitespaces in *RLs by default...